# multi-stage docker build with bundler

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler, docker-multi-stage-build

```
ARG     RUBY_VERSION=3.1.0
ARG     IMAGE_OS=slim-buster
FROM    ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-${IMAGE_OS} as prod-gem-base
ENV     APP_ENVIRONMENT=production 
ENV     RACK_ENV=production
ARG     CI_ACCESS_TOKEN
WORKDIR /contract-service
RUN     apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy build-essential ca-certificates tzdata shared-mime-info git curl openssh-client libpq-dev && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
        gem install bundler:2.3.13 && \
        bundle config --global frozen 1 && \
        bundle config set without 'development test' && \
        mkdir -p -m 600 $HOME/.ssh && ssh-keyscan gitlab.xxx.de >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts && \
        if [ -n $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN ]; then git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.xxx.de /".insteadOf git@gitlab.xxx.de: ; fi
COPY    Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN     --mount=type=ssh bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 && \
        bundle clean --force && \
        rm -rf /usr/local/bundle/cache/*.gem && \
        find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.c" -delete && \
        find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.o" -delete

ARG     RUBY_VERSION
ARG     IMAGE_OS
FROM    ruby:${RUBY_VERSION}-${IMAGE_OS} as prod-core-base
ENV     APP_ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV     RACK_ENV=production
WORKDIR /contract-service
RUN     mkdir -p /tmp/pids && apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends shared-mime-info openssh-client libpq-dev && \
COPY    --from=prod-gem-base /usr/local/bundle/ /usr/local/bundle/
COPY    . .
EXPOSE  3005
CMD     ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "--pidfile", "/tmp/pids/server.pid", "-b", "tcp://0.0.0.0", "-p", "3005"]
```

I am not sure how many ruby people are here. I am creating an with multi-stage build to cache the gems. I am building a production image but when the container is run the bundler outputs error as follows.

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:486:in `materialize': Could not find rubocop-1.31.2, byebug-11.1.3, simplecov-0.21.2, simplecov-cobertura-2.1.0, webmock-3.13.0, cucumber-8.0.0, rspec-3.11.0, rspec-core-3.11.0, rspec_junit_formatter-0.5.1, rack-test-2.0.2, json-2.6.2, parallel-1.22.1, parser-3.1.2.0, rainbow-3.1.1, regexp_parser-2.5.0, rubocop-ast-1.19.1, ruby-progressbar-1.11.0, unicode-display_width-2.2.0, docile-1.4.0, simplecov-html-0.12.3, simplecov_json_formatter-0.1.4, crack-0.4.5, hashdiff-1.0.1, builder-3.2.4, cucumber-ci-environment-9.0.4, cucumber-core-11.0.0, cucumber-cucumber-expressions-15.2.0, cucumber-gherkin-23.0.1, cucumber-html-formatter-19.2.0, cucumber-messages-18.0.0, diff-lcs-1.5.0, multi_test-1.1.0, sys-uname-1.2.2, rspec-expectations-3.11.0, rspec-mocks-3.11.1, rspec-support-3.11.0, ast-2.4.2, cucumber-tag-expressions-4.1.0, ffi-1.15.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:191:in `specs'
cntrct-contract.1.8tfk50ss339q@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/definition.rb:239:in `specs_for'
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler.rb:151:in `setup'
cntrct-contract.1.dfhae8xfhdip@stage-app01-ruh2    |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

The issues is bundler is trying to load the development and test related gems which is not in the final image. Can someone tell me how to do it correctly with multi-stage docker build ?

**Update:** if I add `RUN     bundle config set without 'development test' && bundle` after the `COPY ..` then everything works. I still didn't get the original issue!!! What am I missing ?